# Getting the selected file name from the vault

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Here is code that works in normal folders but it does not work in the vault (solidworks epdm)

More info,if any file in any folder on my computer is selected(focused or highlighted) this code above works 100% .but I got a EPDM SolidWorks Vault folder on my C: Drive , in this vault folder the code above does not provide me with the selected item ,it gives me a blank value . No errors

```
Imports Shell32
Imports SHDocVw
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Function GetExplorerSelectedFiles() As String()
        Dim ExplorerFiles As New List(Of String)
        Dim exShell As New Shell

        For Each window As ShellBrowserWindow In DirectCast(exShell.Windows, IShellWindows)
            If TryCast(window.Document, IShellFolderViewDual) IsNot Nothing Then
                For Each fi As FolderItem In DirectCast(window.Document, IShellFolderViewDual).SelectedItems
                    ExplorerFiles.Add(fi.Name)
                Next
            ElseIf TryCast(window.Document, ShellFolderView) IsNot Nothing Then
                For Each fi As FolderItem In DirectCast(window.Document, ShellFolderView).SelectedItems
                    ExplorerFiles.Add(fi.Name)
                Next
            End If
        Next

        Return ExplorerFiles.ToArray
    End Function

    Private Sub btntest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btntest.Click
            Dim files = GetExplorerSelectedFiles()
            Dim file As String = String.Join(".", files)

            Label1.Text = file
    End Sub

End Class
```

[See "not working image" for more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVTjA.png)

[See "working image" for more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JXuM.png)

Comment: Define "not working". Show the error(s) you get. Show the expected behaviour. Provide a MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: okay if any file in any folder on my computer is selected(focused or highlighted) this code above works 100% .but I got a EPDM SolidWorks Vault folder on my C: Drive , in this vault folder the code above does not provide me with the selected item ,it gives me a blank value . No errors

Comment: It would be better if you edit your question to include the relevant information of your comment..

Comment: thank you for your help hope this is better and i added some screen shots as well,